# OCMock valueForKey failing with NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

In the code I'm testing, I have an NSPredicate and I'm filtering an array:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %d || status == %d", FVFileReadyStatus, FVFileWaitingStatus];
[myArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I have a method to return a mock, which will eventually get added to `myArray`.  `FVFileStatus` is a typedef enum.  Because I'm using a predicate, the predicate is calling `valueForKey`, so I need to stub that out:

```
-(id)mockFVFileHandleWithStatus:(FVFileStatus)status {
    id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[FVFileHandle class]];
    [[[mock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(status)] valueForKey:[OCMArg checkWithSelector:@selector(isEqualToString:) onObject:@"status"]];
    return mock;
}
```

When I run my test, it fails on the filter.  I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException - Reason: Return value does not match method signature`.

I'm not sure how to setup the stub so it will work with an NSPredicate.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very close. The right way to set up the stub is as follows:

```
[[[mock stub] andReturn:OCMOCK_VALUE(status)] valueForKey:[OCMArg checkWithSelector:@selector(isEqualToString:) onObject:@"status"]];
```

This might seem counter-intuitive at first, because the attribute you are trying to stub is of type *int*, and because of that you'd expect to have to use **andReturnValue:**.

However, the actual method that is being called on the mock object is not **status** but **valueForKey:** and the return type for the latter is *id*. So, when using **andReturnValue:** the stub is set up to return a primitive value and then complains when it's asked to provide an object. By the way, the error message could be clearer, I'll look into that.

You can still use the **OCMOCK_VALUE** macro to set up a value object, but by using **andReturn:** you're telling the stub to return that value object, and not the primitive that's wrapped in it, and that is what is compatible with **valueForKey:**'s return type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to use -[OCMArg checkWithSelector:] and can just use the string as the -valueForKey: argument.